# What does the tsql !> operator do?

Tags: t-sql, null, operators

I'd like to know what does this operator do, I coundn't find anything about it.
It would be nice to see some examples of usage.

```
set ansi_nulls [on | off]
expression !> expression (NULL)
```

For example: these queries return the same result (1):

```
select 1 where 1 !> 1;

select 1 where 1 = 1;
```

But nothing is returned from these queries:

```
set ansi_nulls off;
select 1 where null !> null;

set ansi_nulls on;
select 1 where null !> null;
```

Comment: [TSQL comparison operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its stating "[Not greater than](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184364.aspx)".

For example:

```
IF 1 !> 2
BEGIN
    PRINT 'foo'
END
```

This query will `PRINT` "foo", because 1 is **not greater than** 2.

---

1 is not greater than 1, therefore this returns `true`.

Also 1 equals 1, so this will also return `true`.

Hence why both your statements return the same results.

---

Nothing will be returned when comparing `null` because these do not have a value. (ie. `null != null`). So the statement will never be `true`

Comment: Thank you very much, your explication helped a lot!